# Edit lightning "sub-tabs" in metadata

Tags: lightning, metadata

I used lightning app builder to add a "sub tab" to a page that holds a related list. Now I need to deploy that tab using Metadata api. I have never worked with "flexipages" before. Which tags do I need to copy to fully deploy a sub tab? Right now I am looking at this, but I can't tell if this what I really need:

```
        <componentInstances>
        <componentInstanceProperties>
            <name>body</name>
            <value>Facet-4d465c3a-9791-4035-bdb2-2376d181ea93</value>
        </componentInstanceProperties>
        <componentInstanceProperties>
            <name>title</name>
            <value>Practice Management Guides</value>
        </componentInstanceProperties>
        <componentName>flexipage:tab</componentName>
    </componentInstances>
```

... this is in a parent component :

```
    <flexiPageRegions>
    <componentInstances>
        <componentInstanceProperties>
            <name>active</name>
            <value>true</value>
        </componentInstanceProperties>
        <componentInstanceProperties>
            <name>body</name>
            <value>detailTabContent</value>
        </componentInstanceProperties>
        <componentInstanceProperties>
            <name>title</name>
            <value>Standard.Tab.detail</value>
        </componentInstanceProperties>
        <componentName>flexipage:tab</componentName>
    </componentInstances>
    <componentInstances>
        <componentInstanceProperties>
            <name>active</name>
            <value>false</value>
        </componentInstanceProperties>
        <componentInstanceProperties>
            <name>body</name>
            <value>relatedTabContent</value>
        </componentInstanceProperties>
        <componentInstanceProperties>
            <name>title</name>
            <value>Standard.Tab.relatedLists</value>
        </componentInstanceProperties>
        <componentName>flexipage:tab</componentName>
    </componentInstances>
    <componentInstances>
        <componentInstanceProperties>
            <name>body</name>
            <value>Facet-4d465c3a-9791-4035-bdb2-2376d181ea93</value>
        </componentInstanceProperties>
        <componentInstanceProperties>
            <name>title</name>
            <value>Practice Management Guides</value>
        </componentInstanceProperties>
        <componentName>flexipage:tab</componentName>
    </componentInstances>
    <mode>Replace</mode>
    <name>maintabs</name>
    <type>Facet</type>
</flexiPageRegions>
```

I tried to deploy this and I got an error:

> The facet Facet-4d465c3a-9791-4035-bdb2-2376d181ea93 is defined by a component in the FlexiPage but not actually used.

Another thing that confuses me is when I look at this 'flexipage' in eclipse I see all these markup tabs, what's going on here: 
[image]

Comment: One question though: Why you dont just edit page and than move it using changeset or retrieve metadata using some tool (Eclipse/Illuminated Cloud/Welkin Suite/SFDX/ANT/Whatever)?

Comment: True, I'm trying to push it to a new environment but maybe I can just do it as a manual step since it's so simple thanks !

Comment: You're right this doesn't really need version control

Comment: Well you can always add it to the version control without a problem, just retrieve changed metadata (flexipage) and dont edit it manually just commit changes. There shouldnt be any problems with that :)  And even if later build fails you can act after. Only issue i can think of is that vcs wont recognize what is changed and what is Just new stuff, but it shouldnt be a problem in this specific scenario

Comment: Just a warning, Force.com IDE for Eclipse is now a full two years behind in API versions. If you use it to retrieve a Flexipage that uses any newish features (such as conditional visibility) those new features get stripped out and lost when you try to re-deploy.